# The UPDATE permission was denied on the object

Tags: php, sql-server, permissions

I'm connecting to a remote Microsoft server running `MsSQL` via `PHP.`  The code looks something like:

```
$con = mssql_connect('0.0.0.0:123', 'user', 'pass')
    or die(log_mssql_error(__FILE__, __LINE__, mssql_get_last_message()));
mssql_select_db('ShipWorks', $con)
    or die(log_mssql_error(__FILE__, __LINE__, mssql_get_last_message()));

mssql_query($query = "UPDATE [Foo].[dbo].[Bar] SET Biz = 'ABC' WHERE Baz = 'XYZ'")
    or die(log_mssql_error(__FILE__, __LINE__, mssql_get_last_message(), $query));
```

I receive the following error

> The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'Bar', database 'Foo', schema 'dbo'.

- In the object explorer, in 'Server' > Databases > 'Foo' > Security > Users > 'user' I've set `GRANT` on all the securables.
- And in 'Server' > Databases > 'Foo' properties, I'ved added the 'user' user and given all `GRANT` permissions as well.

I feel like I've covered all the bases but I'm still getting the permission denied error. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've set GRANT on all the securables.

You want to assign roles to write data for a specific database. When I read this correct you clicked everthing to do this.

Now I think that your user is member of the role `db_datawriter` and `db_denydatawriter`. Please remove the role `db_denydatawriter` and try it again.